# MS-Access : Query to generate dates for recurring events?

Tags: ms-access

I'm not too familiar with the more complex queries and I'm having an issue finding some examples to take apart to utilize..

```
Event Name  | Due Date   | Frequency    |Frequency UOM
S-XYC-001   | 10/17/2020 |  360         |    D
S-XYA-003   | 6/1/2020   |  90          |    D
S-XYC-004   | 4/3/2020   |  180         |    D
```

So, we have a set of work that has an initial due date provided, and an expected frequency along with a unit of measurement (I've converted all my frequencies into days as there was previously a mix of days, quarterlies, months..).

I've been asked to generate a forecast of events in 2020. So, using the above source table we'd expect our list to look like this:

```
Event Name  | Due Date   | Frequency    | Frequency UOM
S-XYC-001   | 10/17/2020 |  360         |     D
S-XYA-003   | 6/1/2020   |  90          |     D
S-XYA-003   | 8/30/2020  |  90          |     D
S-XYA-003   | 11/28/2020 |  90          |     D
S-XYC-004   | 4/3/2020   |  180         |     D
S-XYC-004   | 9/30/2020  |  180         |     D
```

I'm really not quite sure what type of query to apply to get these results, Or honestly what to look for to get some examples I can utilize to do what I need to.

Comment: I would start with just writing down what you need to accomplish in psuedo code...something like this 
-Query current table-
-loop through results-
-add current record-
-add frequency to the due date -
 -check to see if adding date extends to 2021-
  -if not add it to the db-
  -else go to the next record-
-repeat for each record-

Comment: Simplest approach may be VBA procedure writing records to temp table - as described by Sorceri pseudocode.

Comment: As for frequencies, if a frequency of 90 days originally was every 3 months, you'll be getting the wrong event dates. Just a thought ;)

Comment: What frequencies can occur? For Months only I could think of a table with vals 1 to 12 and the calc the next year by a carthesian join on`Select MonthNumber From Months Where MonthNumber Mod MonthsPerInterval = 0 `and create the new date with Dateadd("m",MonthNumber,OldDate)

Answer (score 2):

First, change your frequency to months - 12, 3, and 6 respectively - to obtain the correct result dates.

Then, create a small query and save it as **Ten** as it simply returns 0 to 9:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
FROM 
    MSysObjects;
```

Use that in this generic query that is capable of generating any sequence of date/time in the entire range of *DateTime*:

```sql
PARAMETERS 
    [Interval] Text ( 255 ), 
    [Number] IEEEDouble, 
    [Date] DateTime, 
    [Count] IEEEDouble;
SELECT 
    [Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100+[Ten_3].[N]*1000+[Ten_4].[N]*10000+[Ten_5].[N]*100000+[Ten_6].[N]*1000000+[Ten_7].[N]*10000000 AS Id, 
    DateAdd([Interval],Fix([Number])*([Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100+[Ten_3].[N]*1000+[Ten_4].[N]*10000+[Ten_5].[N]*100000+[Ten_6].[N]*1000000+[Ten_7].[N]*10000000),[Date]) AS [Date]
FROM 
    Ten AS Ten_0, 
    Ten AS Ten_1, 
    Ten AS Ten_2, 
    Ten AS Ten_3, 
    Ten AS Ten_4, 
    Ten AS Ten_5, 
    Ten AS Ten_6, 
    Ten AS Ten_7
WHERE 
    ((([Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100+[Ten_3].[N]*1000+[Ten_4].[N]*10000+[Ten_5].[N]*100000+[Ten_6].[N]*1000000+[Ten_7].[N]*10000000)<[Count]) 
    AND 
    (([Interval]) In ("s","n","h","d","w","ww","m","q","yyyy")) 
    AND 
    ((Fix([Number])*([Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100+[Ten_3].[N]*1000+[Ten_4].[N]*10000+[Ten_5].[N]*100000+[Ten_6].[N]*1000000+[Ten_7].[N]*10000000) Mod IIf(Fix([Number])=0,1,Fix([Number])))=0) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_0.N)<=[Count]\1) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_1.N)<=[Count]\10) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_2.N)<=[Count]\100) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_3.N)<=[Count]\1000) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_4.N)<=[Count]\10000) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_5.N)<=[Count]\100000) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_6.N)<=[Count]\1000000) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_7.N)<=[Count]\10000000));
```

Save it as **DatesSequence**.

This you can run with the parameters:

```
Interval: "m"
Number: 3, 6, or 12
Date: Due Date
Count: The count of future event dates to list
```

Results:

[image: Sequence]

[image: Sequence]

You could modify the query to filter out dates later than 2020.

Comment: Thanks! This is very similar to what i'm looking for. Is there a method to feed the parameter values from a table set that that it would automatically apply the query?

Comment: Yes, but that will be very slow as this is a highly optimised _Cartesian_ (multiplying) query which will be considerably slowed down by introducing yet a table. So, I would run a loop in VBA that runs the query for each event, writing the data to a (temporary) table to be used by the final report or form.

Comment: @Gustav some explaination, how this works would be interresting ;)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: You'll notice, that the included eight aliased _Ten_ queries have no joins, thus you have a _Cartesian_ or multiplying query, meaning that the counts of records of these are multiplied, potentially generating 10^8 records - enough to generate each second from _100-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59_. That'll take some time and is rarely needed, thus the extensive WHERE statement limits the total count to what is needed. The generated numbers are used in _DateAdd_ to create the series of date/time with a requested interval. Happy New Year!

Comment: Now I got it ;) Thanks for explanaition! Should add that to answer! Happy New Year!