# Access SQL query to compare two tables and list all data, not just those that dont match

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a fillable form to have our employees self assess each day. I seem to have the form and table with the data working properly. I have split the database into front end for the form and back end for the data so I can distribute the form to each user PC and use access runtime. I have 2 tables. One table `Employee Info` will have fields `Employee Name` and `Employee Number`, this table will hold all the employees within the organization. The second table "Assessment" holds the data being entered into the form which the fields are: `Employee Name`, `Employee Number`, `Self Assessed` with a yes/no check box and `Date Signed`. The Date signed field is generating the date automatically when they hit the submit button on the form. I'm having trouble writing a query that lists each Employee Name and Employee Number from the Employee Info table as well as Date Signed from Assessment even if they didn't use the form that day. So basically if someone didn't self assess on that date it would show a blank in the Date Signed field. I can only get it to show those who did submit an entry for that date, not showing all the others who didn't.

I have this but it's not showing those who didn't submit on those dates:

```
SELECT [Employee Info].ID, [Employee Info].[Employee Name], [Employee Info].[Employee Number], Assessment.[Date Signed]
FROM [Employee Info] LEFT JOIN Assessment ON [Employee Info].[Employee Name] = Assessment.[Employee Name]
WHERE (((Assessment.[Date Signed])>=[Start Date] And (Assessment.[Date Signed])<=[End Date]))
ORDER BY Assessment.[Date Signed];
```

Hopefully I'm explaining this correctly. I'm trying to get back into MS Access after many years.

Comment: You should be able to apply your WHERE conditions in the ON clause instead which will restrict the records in the `Assessment` table BEFORE it's joined instead of after. I'm not adding as an answer though since I'm not 100% sure that is allowed in Access. If it isn't then you can create a query on top of `Assessment` to restrict for these dates and then join that subquery in this query in place of the `Assessment` table join.

Comment: Can be helpful to show sample data as text tables.

Comment: Advise not to use spaces in naming convention. Also, Assessment should not have field for employee name, just employee number. Name parts should be in separate fields - FirstName, MiddleName, LastName.

Comment: Showing all employees for a particular date, even if there is not yet an assessment record, gets complicated and would likely result in a non-editable query.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494027/ms-access-query-to-generate-dates-for-recurring-events/59499053#59499053) is how to list all dates within an interval.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I will definitely stop using spaces in my table and field names. I got it working with the first query in the answers. it does what I need without going crazy. I need to bone up on my access skills. it's been 20 years and I don't remember much.

Comment: Creating dataset of all dates within a range by Gustav's suggestion will perform slowly. Then it would have to be used in another query along with Employees and Assessments to show actual data (possibly a UNION query). With large tables, these type of queries can perform so slowly so as to be non-functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query to show just those who have not assessed for a particular date would be like:

`SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmpID NOT IN (SELECT EmpID FROM Assessment WHERE DateSigned = [enter date here];`

Or a 'find unmatched' query (Access has a wizard for this):

`SELECT * FROM Employees LEFT JOIN Assessment ON Employees.EmpID = Assessment.EmpID_FK WHERE Assessment.EmpID_FK Is Null AND DateSigned = [enter date here];`

[enter date here] could reference a control on form for the parameter input.

`WHERE DateSigned = Forms!FormName!textboxname`

A UNION query using the above could show all employees:

```
SELECT EmpID, DateSigned FROM Assessments WHERE DateSigned = [enter date here]
UNION SELECT EmpID, DateSigned FROM Employees LEFT JOIN Assessment ON Employees.EmpID = Assessment.EmpID_FK
      WHERE Assessment.EmpID_FK Is Null AND DateSigned = [enter date here];
```

Data in this query will not be editable.

To see a record for each employee for each date and be able to edit data, then records must exist in Assessments table. "Batch" creating records can be accomplished with INSERT SELECT action SQL.
`INSERT INTO Assessments(EmpID_fk, DateSigned) SELECT EmpID, #a date value here# FROM Employees;`
Now employee can modify checkbox field when they accomplish assessment.

Perhaps there should be two date fields: AssessmentDate, SignedDate. SignedDate would be instead of just simple checkbox. Then the INSERT action would use AssessmentDate.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. The first query: SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmpID NOT IN (SELECT EmpID FROM Assessment WHERE DateSigned = [enter date here]; seems to do what I need (with some adjustment), it shows those who didn't sign for a specific date, it also shows those who didnt enter their employee number or name correctly, but I have separate queries to show that. I will definitely stop using spaces in my names. I realize that's what the [ ] are used for. we really should hire a programmer/DB administrator, but that has fallen on me and my severely rust access skills. thanks again.

Comment: If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted.

Comment: So when you use EmpID_fk, why did you add the _FK to it? what does that represent? while the first query does give me a list of those who didn't sign for a single day, it gets wonky for a date range. I was hoping to get a list of all employees for a given date and then have the Date Signed field be empty for those who didn't submit for that date. So if a date range was entered it would should a list of all employees for the first day, second day, etc. But then have blanks in the date signed field for those that didn't sign. But maybe that's too complicated and not worth doing?

Comment: I added the _FK to distinguish the fields from different tables. Using exact same field name in multiple tables can be confusing. Yes, suggested query was not intended to work for date range - that gets more complicated because records do not really exist for employees that have not done an assessment. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you do not check for null in the WHERE expression. A Null therefore returns Null, which is considered non-matching. I suggest you try the following code:

```
SELECT [Employee Info].ID, [Employee Info].[Employee Name], [Employee Info].[Employee Number], Assessment.[Date Signed]
FROM 
    [Employee Info] 
LEFT JOIN 
    Assessment 
ON [Employee Info].[Employee Name] = Assessment.[Employee Name]
WHERE IsNull([Date Signed]) OR (((Assessment.[Date Signed])>=[Start Date] And (Assessment.[Date Signed])<=[End Date]))
ORDER BY Assessment.[Date Signed];
```

In addition to this, I agree with some comments posted by others saying that you should apply the WHERE condition BEFORE doing the LEFT JOIN. This is, you first do a SELECT over the table, and then you apply the JOIN to this SELECT: this is more efficient and it is better SQL programming practice.
More information in [LightningGuide.net](https://LightningGuide.net)